# Print Arraylist with two arrays with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

someone tell me what is wrong. I want to generate a Arraylist with two dynamic arrays with radom numbers. For example i want to print a matrix of 7 rows and 5 columns. And i also wont have duplicates in my matrix.

```
ArrayList<int[]> lottoraws= new ArrayList<int[]>();

    int[] a = new int[5];
    int[] b = new int[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 35 + 1);
        b[i] = rand;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * 35 + 1);
            a[j] = rand2;
    }
    }
    lottoraws.add(a);
    lottoraws.add(b);

    System.out.println("The players row: \n" + Arrays.toString(lottoraws.get(0)));
```

Comment: Extend your code. It's not full, i guess. What is "lottoraws"?

Comment: Ops, sorry, lottoraws is the Arraylist

Comment: How can we tell what's wrong? Nothing seems wrong with your code. But obviously it won't produce a matrix.

Comment: The output i got is "Players row: [33, 22, 32, 23, 30]" And i want to have it like a matrix with 7 rows and 5 columns

Comment: What kind of error u get? It is not clear what is troubling you?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
    int[][] a = new int[7][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < a[0].length ; j++){
            a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 35 + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually not. I need to use a ArrayList because the user will choose the size of rows and columns. Maybe it is possible to use your method, but i want to learn how to do it with arrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, you can change the random scheme as per you need.

```
    ArrayList<int[]> lottoraws = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] a = {};

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        a = new int[5];

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            int rand2 = (int) (random.nextInt(200));
            a[j] = rand2;
        }
        lottoraws.add(a);
    }

    for(int k=0; k< lottoraws.size(); k++){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lottoraws.get(k)));
    }
}
```